# PHP Mysqli query constantly returns false

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create the database tables with the mysqli interface in PHP, however the query call always returns false and the database remains empty (no tables). I don't know what's wrong with this function, I also checked to make sure the database connection was successful and it was.

```
$connection->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
hash VARCHAR NOT NULL
)');
```

Comment: This is where showing [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) is very helpful.

Comment: You need to define a size/length for the hash varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query has a syntax error and hence it is returning as false.

You had missed to add the varchar size of the hash column.

**corrected query**

```
$connection->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    hash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)');
```